# Error: Undefined function or method 'svmtrain' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I am running

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(xTrain, yTrain);
```

and the error I get is

```
Undefined function or method 'svmtrain' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

I am pretty sure xTrain and yTrain are matrices though:

```
size(xTrain)
ans =
544    28


size(yTrain)
ans =
544     1
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: most probably the problem is with your path. Please check your path.. if not change it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the `svmtrain` function isn't on your path. If

```
which svmtrain
```

displays "svmtrain not found", then you should make sure that you have the bioinformatics toolbox (type `ver` and see if it is in the list) and it is in your [path](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/path.html).

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are missing the *bioinformatics toolbox* as others have said. But it could also be that you want the LibSVM library. This was the case in third-party code I had to run. Get the library here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `svmtrain` should be a vector of integers or logicals, where the value in each row corresponds to the values in the same row of the training matrix/vector. It sounds like your case may be more **regression** if you're trying to output double values for the training data. In that case, you may want to look into regression algorithms. If you still want multi-class **classification**, you need to adjust your output accordingly.

Comment: Passing an array of doubles to svmtrain does not produce this error; if you try to do regression with svmtrain, it will say something like: "SVMTRAIN only supports classification into two groups. GROUP contains 544 groups". I think that svmtrain will work for doubles as long as size(unique(yTrain)) == 2.

Answer (score 0):

yes the bioinformatics toolbox is the key point!
install it using a longer key! you will see it in your custom intall selection!